# Dietel 11.19 how to add pre and post conditions

Tags: java

Write a program that shows a constructor passing information about constructor failure to an exception handler. Define class SomeClass, which throws an Exception in the constructor. Your program should try to create an object of type SomeClass and catch the ex- ception that’s thrown from the constructor.

How would one add pre and post conditions to this code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo3 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    SomeClass testException;

    try
    {
        testException = new SomeClass();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}

public class SomeClass{


  public SomeClass () throws Error { 
    throw new Exception();

  } 
}
```

Comment: What pre- and post-conditions do you want to add?

Comment: I want to add a pre-condition that checks to see if an input is the correct type and a post condition that returns a boolean. So for instance, a precondition that checks that input within a certain range is entered, and a post-condition that will return true/false.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense based on the code and the first paragraph of your question.  *What* input?  What's the connection to the class that throws an exception in its constructor?

Comment: Hah, OK, I must be confused by what pre and post conditions are used for.  You're right, there's no input in either class, but my original question was how would I add condition checking to this code? Basically, I have no idea what conditions I want to check for, or why I'm even using them in the first place. This was a requirement for an assignment, and instead of the instructor explaining this in lecture, I'm forced to beg for help from charitable souls on here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a constructor that takes two params and throw exception there instead. Also, you can assert some pre and post conditions pro-grammatically if you would like to validate some values. I hope it helps. Your code may look like the following:

```
public class Demo3 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

  Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter the firstNumber:");

  int a=scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter the secondNumber:");

  int b=scan.nextInt();

 //you can write some assertion here to meet the pre-conditions
assert(b>0):"You cannot enter a number less or equal to zero";

 SomeClass testException;

 try
 {
    testException = new SomeClass(a,b);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred:"+e.getMessage());
   }
 }
 }

public class SomeClass{
  int firstNumber;
  int secondNumber;
  public SomeClass () {

  } 
  public SomeClass (int firstName,int secondName) throws Exception { 
    //the message to show when you have getMessage() invoked
    throw new Exception("Some exception occurrred");

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does help, Thanks! I've reworked my code though, but I don't understand how to throw an exception when and pre or post condition are not met.

How do I throw an exception, such as an InputMismatchException, when a precondition is not met?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo3 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

  Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 10:");

  int a=scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter another number between 0 and 10:");

  int b=scan.nextInt();

 //assertion here to meet the pre-conditions
  assert (a >= 0 && a <= 10) : "bad number: " + a;
  assert (b >= 0 && b <= 10) : "bad number: " + b;

 SomeClass testException;

 try
 {
    testException = new SomeClass(a,b);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred: "+e.getMessage());
   }

 }
 }

public class SomeClass{
  int a;
  int b;
  public SomeClass () {

  } 
  public SomeClass (int a,int b) throws Exception { 

    throw new Exception("You've got an error!");

  } 
}
```